# Issue with my ClickOnce deployed application

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

For the past 2 weeks, I've been facing a significant issue with my ClickOnce deployed application. The application lacks an external update path and operates on the 4.6.1 .NET framework. It holds the status of a fully Microsoft-trusted application with a valid certificate.

I suspect that this issue is related to the .NET framework and its recent updates from Microsoft's Windows update. My application had been functioning flawlessly for the past 2 years prior to these updates.

The specific issue appears to be that Windows is inexplicably removing certain files or libraries from my application. The most common occurrence involves the removal of the Report Viewer. To resolve this, users are required to restart the application and then manually install the Report Viewer. After this installation, the application resumes normal operation.

This problem seems to be affecting many of my clients' machines, particularly those running Windows 10 or Windows 11. Interestingly, there are no such problems with machines running Windows 7.

I've also observed that several other vendors' ClickOnce deployed apps are encountering similar issues with file removal.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance you can provide. Thank you.

I tried reinstalling the framework but without success.

Comment: Check windows defender.  Guess it is deciding to quarantine elements of.your app,  should be able to restore the missing app elements from the defender interface which seems to prevent it getting quarantined again.